# Why is this ColdFusion 8 app causing CPU to spike?

Tags: iis, coldfusion, windows-server-2003, uploadify, cfimage

Thank you for taking the time to look at this question.... Bear with me....

The other day one of our Web Servers stopped serving up web pages. The Web Server is a physical server running Windows Server 2003 R2 Standard Edition Service Pack 2 with IIS 6. It runs ColdFusion 8.0.1 Standard with Java 1.6.0_24. This server has 3 public-facing websites that really don't get much usage. Pages on all three websites were timing out or returning 500 errors.

When I signed on to the server to see what the problem was, I was expecting to see the JRUN service using a ton of memory. The memory was fine, but, I noticed that the CPU was running at or near 100%. About 50% was being used by JRUN and the other 50% by a runaway backup process, which I killed. But then JRUN quickly ate up the CPU and was using close to 100%.

I looked at the ColdFusion logs and noticed several **Java heap space** errors occurring.

I looked at the IIS logs and noticed that there were a bunch of requests to an app which allows one of our customers to upload multiple image files for their products using uploadify. The app is written in ColdFusion, and uses jQuery to call a Web Service that handles the upload and resizes the uploaded images using `<CFIMAGE>`.

After seeing this information in the logs, I figured some part of this app must be the culprit.

I just can't seem to find what exactly caused the Java heap space errors and CPU spike. Any thoughts?

**WebService CFC method:**

```
<cffunction
    name="uploadFile"
    access="remote"
    returntype="Struct"
    output="false"
    returnformat="JSON">
    <cfargument name="FileName" type="String" default="" />
    <cfargument name="FileData" type="String" default="" />

    <cfscript>
        var _response = NewAPIResponse();
        var _tempFilePath = APPLICATION.TempDir & "\" & ARGUMENTS.FileName;
        var _qItem = QueryNew("");
        var _product = CreateObject("component", "cfc.Product");
        var _result = {};
        var _sku = "";

        /*
            Each file must be named [Part Number].[file extension], so, \
            parse the file name to get everything before the file extension
        */
        _sku =
            Trim(
                REQUEST.UDFLib.File.getFileNameWithoutExtension(
                    ARGUMENTS.FileName
                    )
                );
    </cfscript>

    <cfif Len(_sku) GT 20>
        <cfthrow
            message="#ARGUMENTS.FileName#: File Name does not correspond to an existing Part Number." />
    </cfif>

    <cfset _qItem = _product.readSKU(_sku) />

    <cfif NOT _qItem.RECORDCOUNT>
        <cfthrow
            message="#ARGUMENTS.FileName#: File Name does not correspond to an existing Part Number." />
    </cfif>

    <cfscript>
        FileCopy(ARGUMENTS.FileData, _tempFilePath);

        _aMessages =
            _product.setId(
                _qItem.SKU
                ).updateThumbnailImages(uploadFilePath = _tempFilePath);
    </cfscript>

    <cfif ArrayLen(_aMessages)>
        <cfthrow
            message="#ARGUMENTS.FileName#: #_aMessages[1].getText()#" />
    </cfif>

    <cfscript>
        _result["SKU"] = _product.getSKU();
        _result["SMALLIMAGESRC"] = _product.getSmallImageSrc();
        _result["LARGEIMAGESRC"] = _product.getLargeImageSrc();

        ArrayAppend(_response.data, _result);
    </cfscript>

    <cfreturn _response />
</cffunction>
```

**Image Resizing Function:**

```
<cffunction name="updateThumbnailImages" returntype="Array" output="false">
    <cfargument name="uploadFilePath" type="String" required="true" />

    <cfset var _image = {} />

    <cfif FileExists(ARGUMENTS.uploadFilePath)>
        <cfset _image =
            REQUEST.UDFLib.Image.scale(
                imagePath = ARGUMENTS.uploadFilePath,
                maxHeight = 500,
                maxWidth = 700
                ) />

        <cfimage
            action="write"
            source="#_image#"
            overwrite="true"
            destination="#getLargeImagePath()#" />

        <cfset _image =
            REQUEST.UDFLib.Image.scale(
                imagePath = ARGUMENTS.uploadFilePath,
                maxHeight = 300,
                maxWidth = 300
                ) />

        <cfimage
            action="write"
            source="#_image#"
            overwrite="true"
            destination="#getMediumImagePath()#" />

        <cfset _image =
            REQUEST.UDFLib.Image.scale(
                imagePath = ARGUMENTS.uploadFilePath,
                maxHeight = 50,
                maxWidth = 50
                ) />

        <cfimage
            action="write"
            source="#_image#"
            overwrite="true"
            destination="#getSmallImagePath()#" />
    </cfif>
</cffunction>
```

**Image scaling UDFs:**

```
<cffunction name="getDimensionsToEnlarge" returntype="Struct" output="false">
    <cfargument name="imageWidth" type="Numeric" required="true" />
    <cfargument name="imageHeight" type="Numeric" required="true" />
    <cfargument name="minWidth" type="Numeric" required="true" />
    <cfargument name="minHeight" type="Numeric" required="true" />

    <cfscript>
        var dimensions = {
            width = -1,
            height = -1
            };

        if  (
                ARGUMENTS.minHeight > 0
            &&  ARGUMENTS.minWidth > 0
            &&  imageHeight < ARGUMENTS.minHeight
            &&  imageWidth < ARGUMENTS.minWidth
            ) {
            dimensions.width = ARGUMENTS.minWidth;
            dimensions.height = ARGUMENTS.minHeight;
        }

        return dimensions;
    </cfscript>
</cffunction>

<cffunction name="getDimensionsToShrink" returntype="Struct" output="false">
    <cfargument name="imageWidth" type="Numeric" required="true" />
    <cfargument name="imageHeight" type="Numeric" required="true" />
    <cfargument name="maxWidth" type="Numeric" required="true" />
    <cfargument name="maxHeight" type="Numeric" required="true" />

    <cfscript>
        var dimensions = {
            width = -1,
            height = -1
            };

        if  (
                ARGUMENTS.maxHeight > 0
            &&  ARGUMENTS.maxWidth > 0
            &&  (
                    imageHeight > ARGUMENTS.maxHeight
                ||  imageWidth > ARGUMENTS.maxWidth
                )
            ) {
            dimensions.width = ARGUMENTS.maxWidth;
            dimensions.height = ARGUMENTS.maxHeight;
        }

        return dimensions;
    </cfscript>
</cffunction>

<cffunction name="getDimensionsToFit" returntype="Struct" output="false">
    <cfargument name="imageWidth" type="Numeric" required="true" />
    <cfargument name="imageHeight" type="Numeric" required="true" />
    <cfargument name="minWidth" type="Numeric" required="true" />
    <cfargument name="minHeight" type="Numeric" required="true" />
    <cfargument name="maxWidth" type="Numeric" required="true" />
    <cfargument name="maxHeight" type="Numeric" required="true" />

    <cfscript>
        var dimensions = {
            width = -1,
            height = -1
            };

        dimensions =
            getDimensionsToEnlarge(
                imageHeight = ARGUMENTS.imageHeight,
                imageWidth = ARGUMENTS.imageWidth,
                minWidth = ARGUMENTS.minWidth,
                minHeight = ARGUMENTS.minHeight
                );

        if (dimensions.width < 0 && dimensions.height < 0)
            dimensions =
                getDimensionsToShrink(
                    imageHeight = ARGUMENTS.imageHeight,
                    imageWidth = ARGUMENTS.imageWidth,
                    maxWidth = ARGUMENTS.maxWidth,
                    maxHeight = ARGUMENTS.maxHeight
                    );

        return dimensions;
    </cfscript>
</cffunction>

<cffunction name="scale" returntype="Any" output="false">
    <cfargument name="imagePath" type="String" required="true" />
    <cfargument name="action" type="String" default="fit" hint="shrink, enlarge, or fit"/>
    <cfargument name="minWidth" type="Numeric" default="-1" />
    <cfargument name="minHeight" type="Numeric" default="-1" />
    <cfargument name="maxWidth" type="Numeric" default="-1" />
    <cfargument name="maxHeight" type="Numeric" default="-1" />

    <cfscript>
        var scaledDimensions = {
                width = -1,
                height = -1
            };
        var scaledImage = ImageNew();

        scaledImage = ImageNew(ARGUMENTS.imagePath);

        switch (ARGUMENTS.action) {
            case "shrink":
                scaledDimensions =
                    getDimensionsToShrink(
                        imageHeight = scaledImage.getHeight(),
                        imageWidth = scaledImage.getWidth(),
                        maxWidth = ARGUMENTS.maxWidth,
                        maxHeight = ARGUMENTS.maxHeight
                    );

                break;
            case "enlarge":
                scaledDimensions =
                    getDimensionsToEnlarge(
                        imageHeight = scaledImage.getHeight(),
                        imageWidth = scaledImage.getWidth(),
                        minWidth = ARGUMENTS.minWidth,
                        minHeight = ARGUMENTS.minHeight
                    );

                break;
            default:
                scaledDimensions =
                    getDimensionsToFit(
                        imageHeight = scaledImage.getHeight(),
                        imageWidth = scaledImage.getWidth(),
                        minWidth = ARGUMENTS.minWidth,
                        minHeight = ARGUMENTS.minHeight,
                        maxWidth = ARGUMENTS.maxWidth,
                        maxHeight = ARGUMENTS.maxHeight
                    );

                break;
        }

        if (scaledDimensions.width > 0 && scaledDimensions.height > 0) {
            // This helps the image quality
            ImageSetAntialiasing(scaledImage, "on");

            ImageScaleToFit(
                scaledImage,
                scaledDimensions.width,
                scaledDimensions.height
                );
        }

        return scaledImage;
    </cfscript>
</cffunction>
```

Comment: I'm no server expert, but could you try splitting the sites into their own application pools in IIS to isolate the resources between them? Then maybe you could isolate which of the three is causing the most issues.

Comment: Java head space or java heap space?  Also, did all these page requests come from the same ip address?  Maybe you had a very impatient user.  This sort of thing has happened to us.

Comment: @DanBracuk "heap", sorry. Yes, same IP address but that's to be expected as the app handles multiple uploads.

Comment: @Leeish not necessary as I know the site were the problem is occurring. I just can't figure out why it's happening.

Comment: Can you tell the size of images that were uploaded? Someone tried to upload a extremely large file possibly? I mean your code isn't doing anything ground breaking

Comment: I suggest looking at the form itself.  See if there is a way to thwart the click happy people.  Hiding the submit button when the form is submitted often works.

Comment: @DanBracuk There's no form. It's a flash plug-in that uses one button with which the user selects the files, and the flash plug-in calls a web service for each file selected, and the web service performs the file saving and image manipulation. Besides, in the logs, each of the requests had a significantly different number of bytes, so I know it's not the same request being posted multiple times.

Comment: @Leeish the bytes sent on each request varied between about 200KB and about 1500KB (1.5MB). Big, but not huge.

Comment: Yeah, that's not that large enough to cause issues unless there were a lot of requests in a very short amount of time like from a Bot or something.

Comment: @EricBelair I ran into the exact same issue using coldfusion webservices. The issue is a memory leak in Java 1.6 when creating objects inside a webservice. I was able to replicate the problem on our staging server using load ui. With Java 1.6 I was able to get better results by creating the object once in an init function and setting it to the variables scope. I then use a getter request each time i need to use the object which creates a duplication of the object. ie duplicate(variables.object). This combined with updating Java to 1.7 has stopped our server from crashing.

Comment: @AlanBullpitt could you post a code snippet with what you did? I'm confused though. If it was a memory leak, why didn't memory spike? Only CPU spiked? We'll eventually update to Java 1.7, but I can't do that right now.

Comment: @EricBelair I can't answer why it spikes the way it does. I just know that we were able to reproduce the results time and again through load testing purely our webservice. I will post my example code below.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the example code I spoke of in the comments section. This improved the reliability for us but under extreme load we found the issue still occured which is why we moved to Java 1.7. However 1.7 had it's own problems as the performance drops dramatically as outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21758449/coldfusion-10-slower-when-using-java-1-7-compared-to-1-6). Hope it helps.

```
<cffunction name="init" access="private" output="false" returntype="void">
    <cfset variables.instance = StructNew() />
    <!--- create object and set to variables.instance --->
    <cfset setProductObject()>
</cffunction>

<cffunction name="setProductObject" access="private" returntype="void" output="false">
    <!--- create object once and set it to the variables.instance scope --->
    <cfset var product = createObject("component","cfc.Product")>
    <cfset variables.instance.product = product/>
    <cfset product = javacast('null', '')>
</cffunction>

<cffunction name="getProductObject" access="private" returntype="cfc.Product" output="false">
    <!--- instead of creating object each time use the one already in memory and duplicate it --->
    <cfset var productObj = duplicate(variables.instance.product)>
    <cfreturn productObj />
</cffunction>

<cffunction name="uploadFile" access="remote" returntype="struct" returnformat="JSON" output="false">
    <cfargument name="FileName" type="String" default="" />
    <cfargument name="FileData" type="String" default="" />
        <cfscript>
            var _response = NewAPIResponse();
            var _tempFilePath = APPLICATION.TempDir & "\" & ARGUMENTS.FileName;
            var _qItem = QueryNew("");
            var _product = "";
            var _result = {};
            var _sku = "";
            //check init() function has been run if not run it
            if NOT structKeyExists(variables,'instance') {
                init();         
            }

            _product = getProductObject();
            /*
                Each file must be named [Part Number].[file extension], so, \
                parse the file name to get everything before the file extension
            */
            _sku =
                Trim(
                    REQUEST.UDFLib.File.getFileNameWithoutExtension(
                        ARGUMENTS.FileName
                        )
                    );
        </cfscript>

        <cfif Len(_sku) GT 20>
            <cfthrow
                message="#ARGUMENTS.FileName#: File Name does not correspond to an existing Part Number." />
        </cfif>

        <cfset _qItem = _product.readSKU(_sku) />

        <cfif NOT _qItem.RECORDCOUNT>
            <cfthrow
                message="#ARGUMENTS.FileName#: File Name does not correspond to an existing Part Number." />
        </cfif>

        <cfscript>
            FileCopy(ARGUMENTS.FileData, _tempFilePath);

            _aMessages =
                _product.setId(
                    _qItem.SKU
                    ).updateThumbnailImages(uploadFilePath = _tempFilePath);
        </cfscript>

        <cfif ArrayLen(_aMessages)>
            <cfthrow
                message="#ARGUMENTS.FileName#: #_aMessages[1].getText()#" />
        </cfif>

        <cfscript>
            _result["SKU"] = _product.getSKU();
            _result["SMALLIMAGESRC"] = _product.getSmallImageSrc();
            _result["LARGEIMAGESRC"] = _product.getLargeImageSrc();

            ArrayAppend(_response.data, _result);
        </cfscript>

        <cfreturn _response />
</cffunction>
```

Comment: So basically all this does is move the function variable to the VARIABLES scope, right? I don't understand how this would help. Isn't each request to the remote method a different thread and thus initiating a separate instance of the CFC?

Comment: @EricBelair that's what I initially thought as well but after testing I found that wasn't the case. Once the function is loaded into the variable scope it remains there until the file is changed or Coldfusion is restarted. We did load testing with LoadUI and Fusionreactor after these changes we noticed significant performance increases in the number of requests per minute the application could process and the rate in which the Java memory heap climbed was reduced dramatically.

Comment: @EricBelair we also created a new application.cfc for the webservices directory with session management turned off. Each call created a unique session and before we knew it we had 100000 sessions in memory just waiting to time out.

Comment: good call on disabling session management! I'm going to implement this immediately.